# Node.js tcp sockets and linked Docker containers

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, tcp, docker

I have two node apps in two Docker containers.

1. Main web app
2. A profile service using sockets over tcp

I link the `Profile Service` container to the `Main Web App` container using this option when running the Docker container

```
--link srv-profile:srv_profile
```

And it seems to be linking it just fine. I can say this because I am able to see the following in my `Main web app` container:

```
root@8d6247a82b6d:/app# echo $SRV_PROFILE_PORT
tcp://10.1.0.8:4000
root@8d6247a82b6d:/app#
```

The problem I am facing is that my `Main web app` container is not able to establish a connection with my `Profile Service` container. Here is the output when I start my main web app:

```
root@8d6247a82b6d:/app# nodemon server.js
3 Nov 01:22:43 - [nodemon] v1.2.1
3 Nov 01:22:43 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
3 Nov 01:22:43 - [nodemon] watching: *.*
3 Nov 01:22:43 - [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
web.main listening on port 4000...
Connection closed
```

Here is my code for both `Profile Service` and `Main Web App`

**srv-profile\server.js**

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 4000;

// Create a server instance, and chain the listen function to it
// The function passed to net.createServer() becomes the event handler for the 'connection' event
// The sock object the callback function receives UNIQUE for each connection
net.createServer(function(sock) {

    // We have a connection - a socket object is assigned to the connection automatically
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);

    // Add a 'data' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('data', function(data) {

        console.log('DATA ' + sock.remoteAddress + ':');
        console.log(data);
        console.log();

        // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server
        sock.write('You said "' + data + '"');
    });

    // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
    });

}).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

**web-main\server.js**

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

var express             = require('express'),
    logger              = require('morgan'),
    profileManager      = require('./lib/profile-manager');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));

app.listen(4000, function() {
  console.log('web.main listening on port 4000...');

  profileManager.connect();
  profileManager.disconnect();
});
```

**web-main\lib\profile-manager.js**

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();

var _connect = function() {
    client.connect(process.env.SRV_PROFILE_PORT, function() {
        console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + process.env.SRV_PROFILE);

        // Write a message to the socket as soon as the client is connected, the server will receive it as message from the client
        client.write({
            action: 'doSomething',
            data: '1234',
            source: 'web-main'
        });
    });

    // Add a 'data' event handler for the client socket
    // data is what the server sent to this socket
    client.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('DATA: ' + data);
    });

    // Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
    client.on('close', function() {
        console.log('Connection closed');
    });
};

var _disconnect = function() {
    // Close the client socket completely
    client.destroy();
};

module.exports = {
  connect: _connect,
  disconnect: _disconnect
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to run it locally, w/o docker? I made this an exercise for myself and found multiple issues:

- As mentioned before, server should bind to `0.0.0.0` to listen on all interfaces
- Docker file for server must `EXPOSE 4000` (which it seemingly does in your example, since the link works)
- `Socket.connect()` does not accept the docker-style url (i.e. 'tcp://172.17.0.12:4000'), it must be an options object like `{host: 'bla', port: '1337'}` - use [Node's url](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) module to parse the variable provided by docker.
- As far as I can see, your client immediately disconnects right after it initiates the connection (the `disconnect()` call in `profile-manager.js`)
- You can't just write an object to the socket. Sensible choice for encoding would be `JSON.stringify()`

Moreover, since `data` received via the socket is a `Buffer`, using `data.toString('utf-8')` should result in human-readable output.

Working example can be found on https://github.com/joerx/node-docker-tcp-sockets

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code correctly, you're profile service is only listening on 127.0.0.1. However, the web app is calling from another IP Address. Different containers have different IPs. So the profile service is denying the incoming connection because it is coming in to an invalid IP.